# How do I boot from a microSD but have everything on a USB?

Tags: system-installation

I'm currently making a Ubuntu server on my RockPro64 and have a 128GB Supersonic Rage Pro USB stick that I want to use for everything but the bootable image which I have on a 32gb microSD for the boot image. I want the operating system and everything to be ran from this drive. Would it be better for me to just flash the USB stick instead and not bother with the microsd? What is the best course of action?

Comment: https://forum.pine64.org/forumdisplay.php?fid=101

Answer (score 0):

You asked for the best course of action, so I'll start with that first. For snappy performance modern portable SSDs have become fast and cheap and some are culpable of drawing all the power they need from directly a USB port without requiring a power adapter.

Try running Ubuntu from your 128GB Supersonic Rage Pro USB flash drive first, and see if the performance is not unacceptably laggy. After that in descending order of performance there is a slower USB 2.0 flash drive and microSD card.